# How to use Bazel in case of only header files (template classes/function) in C++?

Tags: c++, cmake, build, googletest, bazel

I have the following problem:
Let's say that my project structure is:

```
├── project
│   ├── include
|   |   ├── BUILD
|   |   └── library.hpp
│   ├── src
|   |   ├── BUILD
|   |   └── main.cpp
|   ├── test
|   |   ├── BUILD
|   |   └── library_test.cpp
└── WORKSPACE
```

`library.hpp` is a file which contains implementation of template class and it is included in `main.cpp` and `library_test.cpp`.

How to prepare `BUILD` files so I would not get compilation errors while compiling `library_test.cpp` and `main.cpp` that say:

```
src/main.cpp:2:10: fatal error: shared_ptr.hpp: No such file or directory
    2 | #include "library.hpp"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

What I tried was:

`include/BUILD`

```
load("@rules_cc//cc:defs.bzl", "cc_library")

cc_library(
    name = "library",
    srcs = ["library.hpp"],
    includes = ["include"],
    visibility = [
        "//visibility:public",
    ]
)
```

Above I also tried having `hdrs` and `textual_hdrs` instead of `srcs`.

`test/BUILD`:

```
load("@rules_cc//cc:defs.bzl", "cc_test")

cc_test(
    name = "library_test",
    srcs = ["library_test.cpp"],
    deps = [
        "@gtest//:gtest",
        "@gtest//:gtest_main",
    ],
    includes = ["include"],
    copts = ["-Iproject/include"],
)
```

and to be thorough my `WORKSPACE`:

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:git.bzl", "git_repository")
git_repository(
    name = "gtest",
    remote = "https://github.com/google/googletest",
    branch = "v1.10.x",
)
```

I have a problem to figure it out by myself based on offical bazel tutorials, some presentations or similar questions I saw on the internet. They show only use of cc_library in case where definitions of the functions written in library are in cpp file and it can be compiled into object file.

Answer (score 1):

```py
# BUILD

cc_library(
    name = "library",
    hdrs= ["include/library.hpp"],
    includes = ["include"],
    visibility = [
        "//visibility:public",
    ]
)

cc_test(
    name = "library_test",
    srcs = ["test/library_test.cpp"],
    deps = [
        "@gtest//:gtest_main", # gtest_main already contains gtest
        ":library"
    ],
)

cc_binary(
    name = "binary",
    srcs = ["src/main.cpp"],
    deps = [
        ":library"
    ],
)
```

Notice:

- Use `hdrs`, because `srcs` are not visible by dependent targets.
- Do not use separate `BUILD` files for `src`/`include`/`test` directories. In Bazel you should create packages oriented by functionality, not by layer.
- In you code a `library_test` target will not see headers from a `library` target, you must pass it as dependency via `deps` attribute. Bazel use [sandboxing](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/sandboxing.html) TL;DR: actions do not see files, which are not explicitly defined as dependency
- Do not use `copts = ["-Iproject/include"]`. Bazel will do it for you when everything is done correctly: in that case you have to add an `includes` attribute to a `library` target. Include path will be set in a `library_test`, because the test targets depends on the `library`